# Kafka consumer lag and under replication

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka cluster with 20 brokers, replication factor 3 with 1024 partitions.

Right now i am facing these issues as i am monitoring the cluster:

- The Consumer is slow in consumption and have huge consumer lag
- The cluster is imbalanced, meaning certain brokers have more partitions which also causes under replication for the broker
- The Producer is unable to connect to kafka for the under replication broker at times, causing timeout, and the producer is unable to write to the under replication broker.
- For the under replication broker, it has high writes and low reads for the I/O

Question:

- Does consumer lag in the brokers cause under replication in the brokers?
- Does reassigning the partitions in the brokers help in reducing consumer lag?
- Does consumer lag affects other kafka clusters in the same chain if there are connected together to process data?

Answer (score 0):

Lag doesn't affect under replication. High Server IO would, as would low open file handles available.

Reassigning partitions does not affect lag. It may reduce server IO for the brokers with higher partition count, but will increase on others.

Lag has nothing to do with other clusters. Plus, you mentioned you only had one cluster with 20 brokers

> Consumer is slow

Try using Confluent parallel consumer, assuming you're using Java

Comment: i have 1 cluster that i am managing and there are multiple clusters in the environment that i have no visibility of.... So i am consuming from one kafka cluster and at the same time another kafka cluster is consuming from my cluster, so was wondering if the consumer lag will affect other clusters if one consumer have huge consumer lag

Comment: If there is high I/O on the under replication server, does it mean that the consuming from the partitions is slow or the producer writing to the partitions is slow?

Comment: high IO will cause slow operations on both, as well as replication happening on that broker. I suggest adding JMX and Node Prometheus exporters, or using tools like DataDog or NewRelic to give yourself visibility of the hardware utilization. You can also use MirrorMaker between clusters rather than have them "consume each other"

Comment: If thats the case, how do i determine using CLI whether it is the producer or consumer causing high I/O given that i dont have additional tools like JMX installed on the brokers?

Comment: JMX is included with any Java process, but you can't determine that. It could even be an external process on the broker itself that's causing high writes on its disk/RAM, or computationally taking many cpu cycles